# Easing Function in JavaScript - set change in value to 0

Tags: javascript, easing, easing-functions

```
// t: current time, b: beginning value, c: change in value, d: duration
function easeInQuad(t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
}
function easeOutElastic(t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158;
    var p = 0;
    var a = c;
    if (t == 0) return b;
    if ((t /= d) == 1) return b + c;
    if (!p) p = d * .3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
        a = c;
        var s = p / 4;
    } else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
    return a * Math.pow(2, -10 * t) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p) + c + b;
}

easeInQuad(100, 20, 0, 1000)  // 20
easeInQuad(500, 20, 0, 1000)  // 20

easeOutElastic(0, 20, 0, 1000)  // 20
easeOutElastic(500, 20, 0, 1000)  // NaN
easeOutElastic(1000, 20, 0, 1000)  // 20
```

if change in value is 0, `easeInQuad` is always return 20, `easeOutElastic` is also return wrong value.

the change in value can't be 0 ?
How jQuery handle `animate({top: 0})`, set 0 to 0.0001?

---

**i misunderstand what *change in value* meaning. if i want end value be `0`, parameter `c` should be `-20`**

Comment: Do you need any thing else or can we accept my answer and close this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following execution of easeInQuad

```
easeInQuad(100, 20, 0, 1000)
```

I get 20 because of the multiplication of 0 across most of your formula.

```
0*(100/=1000)*100 + 20 = 20
```

After looking at other easing formulas I think this is expected behavior. See jQuery source [here](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js)

Further tests show that changing 0 to 1 should produce out of 20.01 and this trend continues. Again I think this is expected behavior.

Comment: thanks. i misunderstand what change in value meaning. if i want end value be 0, parameter c should be -20.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. jQuery source files have some great examples on how they handle this... I added a link in my answer you should check out!

Comment: Lastly unless you needed anything else would you mind accepting my answer? :)